# Blender panoramic render

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to render 360° panoramic images in Blender, usable to make a 360° pano presentation?

Comment: The Cycles render engine can render panoramic images, e.g. equirectangular 360° x 180°. What output format do you need for the panoramic presentation?

Comment: thank you Robert, equirectangular 2 to 1 is what i need, so that's OK.

Answer (score 11):

Rendering panoramic images is possible with the Cycles render engine. Open the *Render Properties* and set the *Render Engine* to *Cycles*.

[image: Set render engine]

Switch to the *Output Properties* and set the render resolution for X and Y. Ensure that they have a 2:1 ratio.

[image: Output resolution]

Select the active *Camera* in your scene and open the *Object Data Properties*. Set the *Type* to *Panoramic* and choose *[Equirectangular](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/cameras.html#equirectangular)* for the *Panorama Type*.

[image: Camera settings]